# Вывод всей базы в активити

Tags: java, android, база-данных

В главном активити создается база, в которую ведется запись изменений в ходе работы приложения `main_activity`:

```
DBHelper dbHelper;
final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bal1_database";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String SUM_TABLE = "sumt";

    public static final String DATE = "date";
    public static final String SUMM = "summ";
    public static final String COMMENT = "comment";



    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    private static final String DB_CREATE_SCRIPT = "CREATE TABLE "
            + SUM_TABLE + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + DATE + " LONG, "
            + SUMM + " INTEGER, " + COMMENT + " TEXT NOT NULL);";



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DB_CREATE_SCRIPT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + SUM_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Далее создан `activity2.java`, в который необходимо вывести все содержимое базы в виде:

```
id|date                   |summ|comment
1 |15.10.2015 15:55       |333 |груша
2 |15.10.2015 15:56       |234 |яблоко
```

`activity2.xml` выглядит следующим образом:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="blablabla.activity2"
android:background="#FAFAFA">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/archive_bd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="88dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Вопрос следующий: есть пример или как реализовать вывод всей таблицы в одном активити?

Конечно, дальше в данном активити необходимо будет добавить редактирование строки и удаление ее. Но это уже второй вопрос.

Для начала с выводом надо разобраться...

UPD:
Помощь в решении вопроса была найдена тут: gitter.im/rus-speaking/android
Детальное описание решения вопроса есть тут: 
http://androiddocs.ru/vidzhet-recyclerview-prostoj-primer/
Всем спасибо за внимание, и попытку помочь.

Comment: Ну так вытащите данные из базы и отобразите... В чём кокретно проблема то? Не можете вытащить? Не можете отобразить?

Comment: не могу вытащить, чтоб конкретно мой активити вытащился...

Comment: Если вы считаете, что просьба фактически написать за вас программу по выводу данных из БД - конкретный вопрос, то вы обратились не на тот ресурс.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Видать я не правильно вопрос задал. Попробую тогда сам разобраться, если пойму как вопрос конкретней сделать, задам повторно. Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как вопрос слишком общий для однозначного ответа, получите вместо закрытия по причине "Слишком общий.." некоторый алгоритм действий:

1. Создаете класс работы с БД одним из методов которого будет возврат курсора (класс `Cursor`) с выборкой всей базы данных.
2. Создаете разметку одного айтема для списка, который задаст вид одной строки в списке (`RecyclerView`) - будет содержать поля для вывода значений одной записи БД.
3. Создаете кастомный адаптер на основе `SimleCursorAdapter` который  будет заполнять айтемы списка на основе полученного в пункте1 курсора.
4. Связываете список с вашим кастомным адаптером.
5. Смотрите на результат.

Примеров реализаций всех этих пунктов в инете более, чем достаточно.

В дальнейшем, пожалуйста, задавайте вопросы по конкретным локальным проблемам, а лучше воспользуйтесь поиском по этому ресурсу, который создан СПЕЦИАЛЬНО для того, чтобы НАХОДИТЬ ответы на вопросы (и уже только потом спрашивать, если удовлетворительного ответа не нашлось), так все ответы по всем пунктам моего списка уже написаны по несколько раз и очень подробно.

Учтите, что такой формат вопросов, как ваш не приветствуется на этом ресурсе, так как для полноценного ответа требуется очень большой объем текста, а решать, фактически, нужно 4 проблемы вместо одной.

Comment: @MaximNaumenko, вам ответили предельно конкретно на ваш действительно общий вопрос. Вы пишите, что много пробовали, но ничего не вышло. Разбейте свою задачу на части и задавайте вопросы по частям. Некоего стандартного способа реализации вашей задачи не существует. Так что давайте по пунктам: 1) У вас получается получить данные из БД?

Comment: @MaximNaumenko Из представленного вами кода и описания проблемы, в ответе гораздо больше, чем вы могли бы расчитывать. Судить о качестве вопроса позвольте тем, кто на него пытается ответить или решайте сами ваш "конкретный" вопрос, в котором информации по проблеме - ноль. Потому что "как сделать вывод из БД" это не конкретная проблема.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Видать я не правильно вопрос задал. Попробую тогда сам разобраться, если пойму как вопрос конкретней сделать, задам повторно. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @MaximNaumenko Напишите в вопросе именно то, что у вас не получается - не общую конечную задачу, а локальную конкретную проблему. Выше пять пунктов, реализовав которые, вы получите желаемый результат. Какой из них вызывает у вас затруднения? По нему и пишите вопрос. Например - "Не могу получить курсор из БД", делаю так то (+код), написал такой класс, должно быть то то , а получается такое то.

Comment: Вот что я просил: http://androiddocs.ru/vidzhet-recyclerview-prostoj-primer/, почему-то на gitter.im меня сразу поняли, и не стали закидывать камнями! Спасибо!